# Issue when adding Confirmable in Devise - [ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1, devise-confirmable, ruby-2.6

I've been setting up Devise Confirmable for my development environment Rails 5.1.7 app.

My initializers/devise.rb looks like:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.secret_key = '########################'
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.pepper = "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
  config.unlock_strategy = :none
  config.maximum_attempts = 3
  config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomAuthenticationFailure
  end
    config.expire_password_after = 90.days
end
```

and my enviroments/development looks like:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost", :port => '3000'}
  config.hostname = ''
  config.relative_url = ''
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    tls: 'true',
    address: '***.***.com',
    port: '25',
    domain: '2222.com',
    authentication: :login,
    user_name: '11111@22222.com',
    password: '111111'
  }
```

> When I sign in for an account, from the UI, I get the below error:
>
> - **ArgumentError at /users/login wrong number of arguments (given 0,    expected 1) activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/persistence.rb def 
>     update(attributes)**

For the request parameter
*{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***********", "user"=>{"login"=>"admin", "password"=>"***"}, "commit"=>"Login", "controller"=>"devise/sessions", "action"=>"create"}*

> Error shown in the backend console -
>
> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1):
>   (eval):1:in `block in compile_lambda'

Database fields added for confirmable are :

```
## Confirmable
t.string   :confirmation_token
t.datetime :confirmed_at
t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

The confirmations_controller looks like -

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource) # In case you want to sign in the user
    root_path
  end
end
```

In routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => '/login', :sign_out => '/logout'}, :controllers => {:passwords => "passwords", :registrations => "registrations", confirmations: 'confirmations'} do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :new_user_session
    post "/login" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    root "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/sessions/new", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/logout", :to => "sessions#destroy"
    get "/users/logout", :to => "devise_sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Stack trace:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0
expected 1)
["/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:277:in `update'"
"(eval):1:in `block in compile_lambda'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `instance_exec'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in conditional'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:259:in `all?'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:259:in `block in conditional'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `block in invoke_after'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `each'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in `invoke_after'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_commit_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:343:in `committed!'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:86:in `commit_records'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:178:in `block in commit_transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:168:in `commit_transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:207:in `block in within_new_transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/transaction_retry-1.0.3/lib/transaction_retry/active_record/base.rb:32:in `transaction_with_retry'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:308:in `block in save'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `rollback_active_record_state!'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:307:in `save'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:42:in `save'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb:62:in `forget_me!'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/controllers/rememberable.rb:32:in `forget_me'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/hooks/forgetable.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:274:in `block in logout'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:272:in `each'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:272:in `logout'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/hooks/activatable.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:15:in `block in _run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `each'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/hooks.rb:10:in `_run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:52:in `_run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:191:in `set_user'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:339:in `_perform_authentication'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/proxy.rb:133:in `authenticate!'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `create'"
"/home/user/projects/revremit_refer/app/controllers/devise_sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:108:in `block in run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/marginalia-1.8.0/lib/marginalia.rb:111:in `record_query_comment'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionview-5.1.7/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/better_errors-2.5.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/better_errors-2.5.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/better_errors-2.5.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/request_store-1.4.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/actionpack-5.1.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'"
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@rails_5_1_2/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'"]
```

**NOTE:**
The same issue is seen when tried to create a new user, through rails console.

Comment: Which version of devise are you using? Also can you look at the stack trace of the error

Comment: gem 'devise', '4.6.2' #'3.5.10'
gem 'devise-encryptable', '0.2.0'
gem 'devise-security', '0.14.3'

Comment: When trying user.save, the same issue is seen.

Comment: Is it the same stack trace for user.save? I suspect there is some callback in your application code which updates an active record model (need not necessarily be a user record) on save, and it is not getting the right value. You can look at the stack trace in console by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656139/225268.  Debugging the console error might be easier because controllers are eliminated from the equation.

Comment: For eg. When you call user.update() without passing any attributes, you get the same error. I suspect there is some update() call in some callback in the user model that causes this error.

Comment: When I try to do user.save, I get the same stack trace -

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205149/discussion-between-rajasree-muraleedharan-and-awin).

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this @RajasreeMuraleedharan